# NSOperation exists on NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, concurrency, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Does anyone know a way of telling if an NSOperation is already on a NSOperationQueue without having to actually get the list of operations and compare with each of the items?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the list, but it's not that taxing. If `queue` and `operation` are your objects:

`[[queue operations] containsObject:operation];`